# How to stop React from rendering comments

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

When I inspect the markup rendered by react on the server, I see a lot of comments like:

```
<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 28 --><!-- /react-text -->
```

How do I make react stop rendering them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Those are needed for React to do its job as far as knowing how to remove/replace items in the DOM. This is an improvement over the previous way React did things, which was `data-reactid` attributes everywhere.

Comment: Though it's true that React needs it for dynamic content, static content is another story: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup

Answer (score 5):

[`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) does exactly that.

From that page:

> Similar to [`renderToString`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring), except this doesn't create extra DOM attributes such as data-reactid, that React uses internally. This is useful if you want to use React as a simple static page generator, as stripping away the extra attributes can save lots of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap each "word" and/or space in a tag, the comments will not show up. Not ideal for large returns, but if for some reason you absolutely cannot have those comments in there it is a (not ideal) solution.

Just view the code in the web inspector, you will see the difference.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/73674/

**no comments**

```
return (<div><span>Hello</span><span> </span><span>{this.props.name}</span></div>)
```

**comments**

```
return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>)
```